Running shell snippet on windows via GNUmake
I am working on windows build system with some wrapper around GNUmake.
Makefile snippet:-
    ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),win32)
      TEST_VERSION := $(shell $(PERL) -ne "if(m/LFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\d+[A-Za-z])/){ print $$1; }" $(TEST_DIR)/elf.h)
    else ifneq ($(filter $(TARGET_OS),Linux Darwin),)
      TEST_VERSION := $(shell $(PERL) -ne "if(m/LFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\d+[A-Za-z])/){ print \$$1; }" $(TEST_DIR)/elf.h)
    endif

Error:-
`/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/src/PERL/5.32.1.1/perl/bin/perl.exe -ne \if(m/ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\d+[A-Za-z])/) print $1; \ c:/src/test/utilities/elf/elf.h'`

I am getting the expected value from a file $(TEST_DIR)/elf.h but in my build log i always see above warning.
How can get around it? Please help.
I want to suppress above warning from the build log.

Where did you download Make? Is it make or mingw32-make?

The weird quoting you see in the error message reveals what's wrong. It's unclear what produces that or why, but the usual workaround if you can't completely ditch Windows (do it; you can thank me later) is to store the script in an external file and call it with $(shell $(PERL) filename.pl $(TEST_DIR)/elf.h)

Basically the file has elf.h has string ELFOSABIV_LATEST          8u , Where i am trying to get 8u from that string.
Sorry.. I don't want to maintain separate script.  That's the reason for using perl one-liner. Could you please help me with one liner that fixes the issue.

It looks to me like somehow make is using cmd.exe as your shell on Windows instead of a POSIX shell, or maybe it's using cmd.exe to execute /bin/sh or something weird.  That is messing up your quoting.  The shell situation on Windows is just a big pain.  If you add an explicit SHELL := sh.exe or something like that before this does it help?
